# Association badges improve conversion rates?

Tags: conversions

Has anyone experienced a conversion rate improvement based on association badges/images ? 
I.E. Badges like BBB association logos, that they're a trusted vendor of x, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've developed web sites for customers who chose to use these, but we didn't really see any changes in traffic or conversions after implementing them. I believe most people have gotten to the point where they just blocl out any non-relevant or non-pertinent information on a web page. Basically, if it isn't part of what they are looking for/at, then they tend to ignore it.